# how to post an entire object hidden in a form in php

Tags: php, forms, file, object, hidden

I have an object which is a file in origin and i would like to send this object in a post form.

When i try this :

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'mgmtUser/upload_img_crop/', 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => true)); }}
    <input hidden type="file" name="file" value="<?php $file; ?>">
    <?= Form::hidden('x', '', array('id' => 'x')) ?>
    <?= Form::hidden('y', '', array('id' => 'y')) ?>
    <?= Form::hidden('w', '', array('id' => 'w')) ?>
    <?= Form::hidden('h', '', array('id' => 'h')) ?>
    <?= Form::submit('Crop it!') ?>
    <?= Form::close() ?>
```

The post result is only :
["file"]=> NULL

Why and how I can get all the object, should I encode, serialize...?
I am on laravel 4.
$file is :

> object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#9 (7) {
>   ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   bool(false)
>   ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   string(11) "3bb13ad.jpg"
>   ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   string(10) "image/jpeg"
>   ["size":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   int(8017)
>   ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
>   int(0) ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(14)
>   "/tmp/phpVGS9Cu" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(9)
>   "phpVGS9Cu" }

Comment: What's the value of `$file` that you are passing to the hidden input?

Comment: I put the value in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually trying to send the `$file` **Object** through the form, you'll need to serialize it into some file format (e.g. write to a `.txt` file) and then upload that through the input.

It looks like the `$file` Object contains attributes related to a file you may be trying to upload instead though, not the actual PHP file handle object. If this is the case, you should just change the below line

```
<input hidden type="file" name="file" value="<?php $file; ?>">
```

To be

```
<input hidden type="file" name="file" value="<?php $file.originalName; ?>">
```

**EDIT**

If you need to work with the file handle on after the form submit, try this:

```
<input hidden type="file" name="file" value="<?php echo json_encode($file) ?>">
```

Then when you are on the receiving end, use

```
$file = json_decode($_POST['file']);
```

to access the Object.

Comment: Yes, but with the name, i can't work as a file with for example this function (ImageCreateTrueColor, imagecopyresampled, and $file->move())